# Determine if one folder is subfolder of another javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this function for checking if a root folder has already been added to the list of folders

```
function folderRootFolderExists(newFolder) {
    for (var folder in $rootScope.syncObj.currentFolders){
        if ($rootScope.syncObj.currentFolders.hasOwnProperty(folder)) {
            if (newFolder.indexOf($rootScope.syncObj.currentFolders[folder].folderPath) > -1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The problem is that two paths like this return true:

/user/me/Folder

/user/me/Folder (1)

Is there a known js library for dealing with file path strings or a more robust solution for determining these sort of things?

Comment: What happens if you add a `/` to the end?

Comment: That's the solution!